# sort and subtotal preselected data

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, subtotal

I'm working with a worksheet and at some point within there is a list of costs. However this list changes so can have varying numbers of rows. My ultimate goal is to sort and then subtotal this list of costs. Because the number of rows I want to sort and subtotal are always different, I was thinking I could make a macro that would only work off of preselected data eg the user to select the cells range to apply to be sorted and subtotalled. I can't just work off of all active cells, as there are some rows I don't want to include in the sort and subtotal.

I've recorded the following simple macro to sort and subtotal data, however, you'll note it only works for the cells that were selected when I recorded the macro. Does anybody know how to modify the macro so that the user can firstly manually select the cells range with the mouse and then click a button that automatically sorts the preselected data and subtotals it? any help very appreciated, thank you.

```
Sub Sort_and_Subtotal_CheckBox()

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("dummy").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("dummy").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "B151:B159"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("dummy").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("B151:K156").Select
    Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(10), _
        Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. This will allow the user to select the range by using an Input box.

```
Dim SortRng As Range

Set SortRng = Application.InputBox("Select the range to sort", "Select Range", 0, , , , , 8)

SortRng.Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=SortRng, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: Delete your code fully except `Sub Sort_and_Subtotal_CheckBox()` and `End Sub` and use my code. When you run the macro, you will see an input box. Once you see the input box, you can enter the range in it or you can also select the range by clicking and dragging.

Comment: Can you show a sample of your data and the result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If my answer helped you, could you please accept it?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to obtain the selected range, you could simply request `Selection.Address` in VBA. However, I believe that this assumes that the selection is a block of cells, so this might not always give the desired result (e.g. in case of multiple selected ranges). Another solution might be to convert the list of costs to a table. In your macro you can then simply refer to a named range, namely, the column in the newly created table. The table will work as a dynamic named range and will always include the entire range of values in it. If you can be sure that there will be no data below the list of costs, a second option would be to check the last row that is not empty within the column where the list of costs is stored. Something in the likes of `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` to get the last row of the column that contains the list.